# Eclipse auto suggestions for Unhandled exception type Exception (Java / Weka)

Tags: java, exception, weka

I am trying to write a script that can batch process multiple ARFF files in Weka. However I always get the "Unhandled exception type Exception" error. Eclipse is suggestion to put try-catch statements around every line of code.

After accepting the suggestions the code runs. However it is very unreadeble code if I do it like this. Any body an idea how to fix this Unhandled exception type Exception error?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
import weka.classifiers.functions.LinearRegression;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ArffLoader.ArffReader;
import weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest;


public class Eval{
    public static Instances LoadARFF(String location){
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(location));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ArffReader arff = null;
        try {
            arff = new ArffReader(reader);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return arff.getData();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {     
        //Get all files from training path
        Files.walk(Paths.get("path/to/sets/Train")).forEach(filePath -> {
            if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
                System.out.println(filePath);

                //Get the file name of the train set.
                String fileLocation = filePath.normalize().toString();
                String[] tokens = fileLocation.split("[\\\\|/]");
                String filename = tokens[tokens.length - 1];
                System.out.println("Train file:" + filename + " found!");

                //Get both the train and test set
                String TrainFile = "path/to/sets/Train/"+ filename;
                String TestFile = "path/to/sets/Test/"+ filename;

                //Load the train set
                Instances train = LoadARFF(TrainFile);
                train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() - 1);

                //Load the test set.
                Instances test = LoadARFF(TestFile);
                test.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() - 1);

                //train classifier
                Classifier cls = new RandomForest();
                cls.buildClassifier(train);

                // evaluate classifier and print some statistics
                Evaluation eval = null;
                eval = new Evaluation(train);
                eval.evaluateModel(cls, test);
                System.out.println(cls);
                System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n======\n", false));
            } //if
        });//for each   
    }//Main
}//class
```

The error code is as followed:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    Unhandled exception type Exception
    Unhandled exception type Exception
    Unhandled exception type Exception

    at Eval.main(Eval.java:60)
```

After accepting the Eclipse auto suggestions, the code is about two times a large as before accepting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like...

```
private static void processFile(Path filePath) {
    System.out.println(filePath);

    //Get the file name of the train set.
    String fileLocation = filePath.normalize().toString();
    String[] tokens = fileLocation.split("[\\\\|/]");
    String filename = tokens[tokens.length - 1];
    System.out.println("Train file:" + filename + " found!");

    //Get both the train and test set
    String TrainFile = "path/to/sets/Train/"+ filename;
    String TestFile = "path/to/sets/Test/"+ filename;

    //Load the train set
    Instances train = LoadARFF(TrainFile);
    train.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() - 1);

    //Load the test set.
    Instances test = LoadARFF(TestFile);
    test.setClassIndex(train.numAttributes() - 1);

    //train classifier
    Classifier cls = new RandomForest();
    cls.buildClassifier(train);

    // evaluate classifier and print some statistics
    Evaluation eval = null;
    eval = new Evaluation(train);
    eval.evaluateModel(cls, test);
    System.out.println(cls);
    System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString("\nResults\n======\n", false));
}

private static void processPath(Path path) {
    if(Files.isRegularFile(path)) {
        try {
            processFile(path);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {     
    //Get all files from training path
    Files.walk(Paths.get("path/to/sets/Train")).forEach(Eval::processPath);
}//Main
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
throws Exception
```

from your `main`. Why did you add that?!?

Comment: Otherwise `Files.walk` did not work. I am new to Java, so I accepted the Eclipse suggestion to add the throws Exception to the main class.

Comment: Handle that exception *correctly*. IO errors happen, and you want an error message to be printed then. **Don't use eclipse suggestions that you do not understand in their consequences.** They are known to be wrong rather often (e.g. make static suggestion of eclipse is almost always the wrong thing to do and causes new bugs in return)

Comment: What is the harm of main having `throws Exception` for this application?  It looks like a pretty straightforward sample application.  I'm guessing, if an exception occurs, dumping a stack trace to the console and exiting (what happens when main throws an exception) is perfectly acceptable.  Besides, the `throws Exception` in the main method isn't really causing or related to the complaint in question.  This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: `throws` delegates the responsibility of handling the errors to the caller. Because there is no caller before `main`, this is not satisfied.